# One to many to many relationship, with composite keys

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, database-design

In my game, an archetype is a collection of associated traits, an attack type, a damage type, and a resource type. Each piece of data is unique to each 
archetype. For example, the Mage archetype might look like the following:

archetype:     Mage
attack:        Targeted Area Effect
damage:        Shock
resource:      Mana
trait_defense: Willpower
trait_offense: Intelligence

This is the archetype table in SQLite syntax:

```
create table archetype
(
archetype_id varchar(16) not null,
attack_id varchar(16) not null,
damage_id varchar(16) not null,
resource_type_id varchar(16) not null,
trait_defense_id varchar(16) not null,
trait_offense_id varchar(16) not null,
archetype_description varchar(128),
constraint pk_archetype primary key (archetype_id),
constraint uk_archetype unique (attack_id, damage_id,
                                resource_type_id,
                                trait_defense_id, 
                                trait_offense_id)
);
```

The primary key should be the complete composite, but I do not want to pass
all the data around to other tables unless necessary. For example, there are
crafting skills associated with each archetype which do not need to know any
other archetype data.

An effect is a combat outcome that can be applied to a friend or foe. An effect has an application type (instant, overtime), a type (buff, debuff, harm, heal, etc.) and a detail describing to which stat the effect applies. It also has most of the archetype data to make each effect unique. Also included is the associated trait used for progress and skill checks. For example, an effect might look like:

apply:     Instant
type:      Harm
detail:    Health
archetype: Mage
attack_id: Targeted Area Effect
damage_id: Shock
resource:  Mana
trait_id:  Intelligence

This is the effect table in SQLite syntax:

```
create table effect
(
effect_apply_id varchar(16) not null,
effect_type_id varchar(16) not null,
effect_detail_id varchar(16) not null,
archetype_id varchar(16) not null,
attack_id varchar(16) not null,
damage_id varchar(16) not null,
resource_type_id varchar(16) not null,
trait_id varchar(16),
constraint pk_effect primary key(archetype_id, effect_type_id, 
                                 effect_detail_id, effect_apply_id, 
                                 attack_id, damage_id, resource_type_id),

constraint fk_effect_archetype_id foreign key(archetype_id, attack_id, 
                                              damage_id, resource_type_id) 
                        references archetype (archetype_id, attack_id,
                                              damage_id, resource_type_id)
);
```

An ability is a container that can hold multiple effects. There is no limit to
the kinds of effects it can hold, e.g. having both Mage and Warrior effects in
the same ability, or even having two of the same effects, is fine. Each effect
in the ability is going to have the archetype data, and the effect data.

Again.

Ability tables in SQLite syntax:

```
create table ability
(
ability_id varchar(64),
ability_description varchar(128),
constraint pk_ability primary key (ability_id)
);

create table ability_effect
(
ability_effect_id integer primary key autoincrement,
ability_id varchar(64) not null,
archetype_id varchar(16) not null,
effect_type_id varchar(16) not null,
effect_detail_id varchar(16) not null,
effect_apply_id varchar(16) not null,
attack_id varchar(16) not null,
damage_id varchar(16) not null,
resource_type_id varchar(16) not null,
trait_id varchar(16),
constraint fk_ability_effect_ability_id foreign key (ability_id) 
                                 references ability (ability_id),
constraint fk_ability_effect_effect_id foreign key  (archetype_id, 
                                                     effect_type_id,
                                                     effect_detail_id, 
                                                     effect_apply_id) 
                                 references effect  (archetype_id, 
                                                     effect_type_id, 
                                                     effect_detail_id, 
                                                     effect_apply_id)
);
```

This is basically a one to many to many relationship, so I needed a technical
key to have duplicate effects in the ability_effect table.

Questions:

1) Is there a better way to design these tables to avoid the duplication of
data over these three tables?

2) Should these tables be broken down further?

3) Is it better to perform multiple table lookups to collect all the data? For example, just passing around the archetype_id and doing lookups for the data when necessary (which will be often).

UPDATE:

I actually do have parent tables for attacks, damage, etc. I removed those 
tables and their related indexes from the sample to make the question clean,
concise, and focused on my duplicate data issue.

I was trying to avoid each table having both an id and a name, as both would be candidate keys and so having both would be wasted space. I was trying to keep the SQLite database as small as possible. (Hence, the many "varchar(16)" 
declarations, which I now know SQLite ignores.) It seems in SQLite having both
values is unavoidable, unless being twice as slow is somehow ok when using the 
WITHOUT ROWID option during table creation. So, I will rewrite my database to 
use ids and names via the rowid implementation.

Thanks for your input guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) Is there a better way to design these tables to avoid the
>   duplication of data over these three tables?

and also

> 2) Should these tables be broken down further?

It would appear so.

It would appear Mage is a unique archtype, as is Warrior. (based upon *For example, the Mage archetype might look like the following:*).

As such why not make the archtype_id a primary key and then reference the attack type, damage etc from tables for these. i.e. have an attack table and a damage table.

So you could, for example, have something like (simplified for demonstration) :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS archtype;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS attack;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS damage;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS attack (attack_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, attack_name TEXT, a_more_columns TEXT);
INSERT INTO attack (attack_name, a_more_columns) VALUES 
    ('Targetted Affect','ta blah'), -- id 1
    ('AOE','aoe blah'), -- id 2
    ('Bounce Effect','bounce blah') -- id 3
    ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS damage (damage_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, damage_name TEXT, d_more_columns TEXT);
INSERT INTO damage (damage_name,d_more_columns) VALUES
  ('Shock','shock blah'), -- id 1
    ('Freeze','freeze blah'), -- id 2
    ('Fire','fire blah'), -- id 3
    ('Hit','hit blah')
    ;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS archtype (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, archtype_name TEXT, attack_id_ref INTEGER, damage_id_ref INTEGER, at_more_columns TEXT);
INSERT INTO archtype (archtype_name,attack_id_ref,damage_id_ref,at_more_columns) VALUES
    ('Mage',1,1,'Mage blah'),
    ('Warrior',3,4,'Warrior Blah'),
    ('Dragon',2,3,'Dragon blah'),
    ('Iceman',2,2,'Iceman blah')
    ;
    SELECT archtype_name, damage_name, attack_name FROM archtype JOIN damage ON damage_id_ref = damage_id JOIN attack ON attack_id_ref = attack_id;
```

- Note that the aliases of **rowid** have been used for id's rather than the name as these are generally the most efficient.

  - ***The data for rowid tables is stored as a B-Tree structure containing one entry for each table row, using the rowid value as the key. This means that retrieving or sorting records by rowid is fast. Searching for a record with a specific rowid, or for all records with rowids within a specified range is around twice as fast as a similar search made by specifying any other PRIMARY KEY or indexed value.*** [SQL As Understood By SQLite - CREATE TABLE- ROWIDs and the INTEGER PRIMARY KEY](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid)
  - A **rowid** is generated for all rows (unless WITHOUT ROWID is specified), by specifying `?? INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` column ?? is an alias of the **rowid**.
  - Beware using AUTOINCREMENT, unlike other RDMS's that use this for automatically generating unique id's for rows. SQLite by default creates a unique id (the **rowid**). The AUTOINCREMENT keyword adds a constraint that ensures that the generated id is larger than the highest existing. To do this requires an additional table **sqlite_sequence** that has to be maintained and interrogated and as such has overheads. ***The AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and disk I/O overhead and should be avoided if not strictly needed. It is usually not needed.*** [SQLite Autoincrement](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

The query at the end will result in :-

[image]

---

Now say you wanted types to have multiple attacks and damages per type then the above could easily be adapted by using many-many relationships by introducing reference/mapping/link tables (all just different names for the same). Such a table will have two columns (sometime other columns for data specific to the distinct reference/map/link) one for the parent (archtype) reference/map/link and the other for the child (attack/damage) referenced/mapped/linked.

e.g. the following could be added :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS archtype_attack_reference;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS archtype_attack_reference 
    (aar_archtype_id INTEGER NOT NULL, aar_attack_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY(aar_archtype_id,aar_attack_id)) 
    WITHOUT ROWID; 

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS archtype_damage_reference;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS archtype_damage_reference 
    (adr_archtype_id INTEGER NOT NULL, adr_damage_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY(adr_archtype_id,adr_damage_id)) 
    WITHOUT ROWID
    ;

INSERT INTO archtype_attack_reference VALUES
    (1,1), -- Mage has attack Targetted
    (1,3), -- Mage has attack Bounce
    (3,2), -- Dragon has attack AOE
    (2,1), -- Warrior has attack targetted
    (2,2), -- Warrior has attack AOE
    (4,2), -- Iceman has attack AOE
    (4,3) -- Icemane has attack Bounce
;

INSERT INTO archtype_damage_reference VALUES
  (1,1),(1,3), -- Mage can damage with Shock and Freeze
    (2,4), -- Warrior can damage with Hit
    (3,3),(3,4), -- Dragon can damage with Fire and Hit
  (4,2),(4,4) -- Iceman can damage with Freeze and Hit
;

SELECT archtype_name, attack_name,damage_name FROM archtype 
    JOIN archtype_attack_reference ON archtype_id = aar_archtype_id
    JOIN archtype_damage_reference ON archtype_id = adr_archtype_id
    JOIN attack ON aar_attack_id = attack_id
    JOIN damage ON adr_damage_id = damage_id
;
```

The query results in :-

[image]

With a slight change the above query could even be used to perform a random attack e.g. :-

```
SELECT archtype_name, attack_name,damage_name FROM archtype 
    JOIN archtype_attack_reference ON archtype_id = aar_archtype_id
    JOIN archtype_damage_reference ON archtype_id = adr_archtype_id
    JOIN attack ON aar_attack_id = attack_id
    JOIN damage ON adr_damage_id = damage_id
    ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1 -- ADDED THIS LINE
;
```

You could get :-

[image]

Another time you might get :-

[image]

> 3) Is it better to perform multiple table lookups to collect all the
>   data? For example, just passing around the archetype_id and doing
>   lookups for the data when necessary (which will be often).

That's pretty hard to say. You may initially think gather all the data once and keep it in memory say as an object. However, at times the underlying data may well already be in memory due to it being cached. Perhaps it could be better to utilise part of each. So I believe the answer is, you will need to test various scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably avoid those composite primary keys. 
And use the more commonly used integer with an autoincrement.

Then add the unique or non-unique composite indexes where needed.

Although i.m.h.o it's not always a bad idea to use a short CHAR or VARCHAR as the primary key in some cases. Mostly when easy to understand abbreviations can be used.

An example. Suppose you have a reference table for Countries. With a primary key on the 2 character CountryCode. Then when querying a table with a foreign key on that  CountryCode, then for the human mind it's way easier to understand 'US' than some integer. Even without joining to Countries you'll probably know what Country is referenced.

So here are your tables with a slightly different layout.

```
create table archetype
(
archetype_id integer primary key autoincrement,
attack_id varchar(16) not null,
damage_id varchar(16) not null,
resource_type_id varchar(16) not null,
trait_defense_id varchar(16) not null,
trait_offense_id varchar(16) not null,
archetype_description varchar(128),
constraint uk_archetype unique (attack_id, damage_id,
                                resource_type_id,
                                trait_defense_id, 
                                trait_offense_id)
);

create table effect
(
effect_id integer primary key autoincrement,
archetype_id integer not null, -- FK archetype
effect_apply_id varchar(16) not null,
effect_type_id varchar(16) not null,
effect_detail_id varchar(16) not null,
attack_id varchar(16) not null,
damage_id varchar(16) not null,
resource_type_id varchar(16) not null,
trait_id varchar(16),
constraint pk_effect unique(archetype_id, effect_type_id, 
                            effect_detail_id, effect_apply_id, 
                            attack_id, damage_id, resource_type_id),

constraint fk_effect_archetype_id foreign key(archetype_id) 
                        references archetype (archetype_id)
);

create table ability
(
ability_id integer primary key autoincrement,
ability_description varchar(128)
);

create table ability_effect
(
ability_effect_id integer primary key autoincrement,
ability_id integer not null, -- FK ability
effect_id integer not null, -- FK effect
attack_id varchar(16) not null,
damage_id varchar(16) not null,
resource_type_id varchar(16) not null,
trait_id varchar(16),
constraint fk_ability_effect_ability_id foreign key (ability_id) 
                                 references ability (ability_id),
constraint fk_ability_effect_effect_id foreign key  (effect_id) 
                                 references effect  (effect_id)
);
```